# BMW E90 Aftermarket Head Unit Eonon GA9165B Installation Troubleshoot with Auto StartStop Button

Tags: audio, bmw, bluetooth, head-unit, entertainment-system

I just bought the Eonon GA9165B Android 7" head unit for my 2007 BMW E90 and I think I may have a potential problem with my Auto Start Stop button as I don't think they have considered that some E90s may have this option and that there is a button that comes with it. My problem is that I don't know what to do with the button once the system is installed as it doesn't look like it has an space whatsoever (as in the pictures attached).

Please can someone help!

[image: left is what the system would look like when installed and right contains the Auto Start Stop button circled]

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely, there's a line that goes in between the panel for the head unit itself, and the HVAC controls. The actual head unit itself is separate from everything below it.

[image: Eonon head unit]

Checking the head unit and the E90's interior, I can see what you mean now as the head unit does shift the HVAC controls down towards the bottom. For this case, they make another bracket: https://www.eonon.com/ProductShow.aspx?productNo=A0574

[image: Eonon A0574]

This kit relocates the buttons down to the storage compartment just below.

[image: Relocated buttons]

Comment: Unfortunately, this head unit comes with a bracket for the HVAC and it doesn't have space for any button below it I don't believe.

Comment: @Jay28 Updated my answer with more info. Hopefully this one actually works out for you, because quite frankly I'm not familiar with whatever infinite variations of E90 there is out there...